# How to remove Title Bar from Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to remove Title Bar from Jquery UI Dialog ?

Please check out the red circled area of Dialog in Image I provided. I want to remove this area.

[image: Please check out the red circled area of Dialog. I want to remove this.]

Comment: I'd recommend getting used to using the element inspector in whatever browser you use, as you could have answered this without even searching (not that you did).

Comment: The 'Theming' section in the jQueryUI Dialog Widget documentation should help.
Some css knowledge is required.